# Disable SSL certification in websocket java

Tags: java, ssl, websocket

I have java websocket connection that tries to login to the server followed by establishing the websocket connection. The websocket class has the mechanism to connect the socket connection where's the main class call for the websocket class constructor.

```
WebSocket(URI serverUri, Map<String, String> head) {
        super(serverUri, head);
    }
```

```
socketUri = new URI(sockPath);
Map<String, String> head = new HashMap<>();
head.put("Authorization", "Bearer ".concat(headerToken));
client = new WebSocket(websocketUri, head);
client.setServerWebSocketUrlPathsockPath);
client.connect();
```

How to make the socket connection to disable the SSL certificate check.

Answer (score 1):

While disabling SSL certificate checks is **not** good practice, here is a solution:

The following code comes from [Nakov.com](https://nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/)

```
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
        };
 
        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
 
        // Create all-trusting host name verifier
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };
 
        // Install the all-trusting host verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
```

Comment: I would recommend to use a custom X509ExtendedTrustManager instead of the X509TrustManager as it will partially will disable the SSL verifications. See here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64982379/6777695

Comment: how can I use this in my above code? @Flav

Comment: You just need to execute this code once (before creating your socket). I also suggest you look into @Hakan54 's comment.

Comment: Used the above code before `socketUri = new URI(sockPath);` but didnt worked.

Comment: I have just edited the answer. What is your implementation of WebSocket?

Comment: thanks for help, but im stil getting same error `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present`
any clue how it could be resolved?

Comment: I think that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540289/how-to-fix-the-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative) covers your problem

Comment: used same but no help yet. used `disableSslVerification()` defined in that post above `socketUri = new URI(sockPath);`. Is that right place to call it?

Comment: It should work yes. Have you tried Hakan54's method in the first comment?

Comment: @Jexxer did you manage to solve it? im facing exactly the same issue and everything i tried failed.

Comment: No clue @LeaChescotta